# How much of STL is too much?

Tags: c++, stl, coding-style

I am using a lot of `STL` code with `std::for_each`, `bind`, and so on, but I noticed that sometimes `STL` usage is not good idea.

For example if you have a `std::vector` and want to do one action on each item of the vector, your first idea is to use this:

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), Foo())
```

and it is elegant and ok, for a while. But then comes the first set of bug reports and you have to modify code. Now you should add parameter to call `Foo()`, so now it becomes:

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind2nd(Foo(), X))
```

but that is only temporary solution. Now the project is maturing and you understand business logic much better and you want to add new modifications to code. It is at this point that you realize that you should use old good:

```
for(std::vector::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
```

Is this happening only to me? Do you recognise this kind of pattern in your code? Have you experience similar anti-patterns using `STL`?

Comment: BTW, if in your second example, "X" is the same for all elements. Just pass it to Foo's constructor and store it in the functor instead of binding it. Much simpler.

Comment: You're actually using none of the STL, so you're safe :)

Comment: Just an opinion, but "too much" is when you use features you don't need solely for the sake of using them.  If it's helpful, use it.  If you're worried about overly long names, you can always use a typedef or namespace alias to shorten them (for example, `typedef std::vector::iterator VecIter;`).  The thing with the standard library is, it's usually the cleanest general-case way to do something on a given compiler, simply because either the compiler's creators or the people that know it best (if not the creators) will write its implementation.  Don't be afraid to use it when it's useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/bind/bind.html) with std::for_each solves this problem in a clean way.   Or you can use [BOOST_FOREACH](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/foreach.html).

Example of std::for_each:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), boost::bind(&C::f, _1, param));
```

Example of BOOST_FOREACH:

```
std::list<int> list_int( /*...*/ );
BOOST_FOREACH( int i, list_int )
{
    // do something with i
}
```

Comment: ...until you get to 10 parameters, that is! :)

Comment: at which point you group them together within a struct :)

Comment: No, at which point you reconsider the architecture that requires a function to have 10 parameters ;)

Comment: That's exactly what I do. std::for_each is so ugly. BOOST_FOREACH is so much better

Answer (score 10):

It can go the opposite way too though. Suppose you start out with an operation that only takes a couple of lines. You don't want to bother creating a function that will only be called once, just to condense the loop, so you write something like:

```
for ()
{
    // do
    // some
    // stuff
}
```

Then as the operation you need to perform gets more complex, you realize that pulling it into a separate function makes sense so you end up with

```
for ()
    do_alot_more_stuff();
```

And then modifying it to be like your original method makes sense to condense it down further:

```
std::for_each(begin, end, do_alot_more_stuff);
```

*In the end, how hard is it to really change a for_each to a for loop, or vice versa? Don't beat yourself up over tiny details!*

Answer (score 5):

Use it like any other language tool.  When it makes your life easier, use it.  When it becomes cumbersome, do something else.  It's not as if it's really hard to refactor a loop one way or another, when requirements change.

Comment: Exactly. What's wrong with changing code?

Answer (score 3):

Similar to your issue, I often notice that the "functor" pattern / idiom in C++ is actually quite unwieldy.  That's why I'm looking forward to [Lambda Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Lambda_functions_and_expressions) in C++0X.  Some of that is possible with boost::lambda now.

Comment: OMG, the syntax... 0X has 8 more months till it ends plus 3+ years until major compiler vendors catch up. That will be a long time.

Comment: @Anton: It's already in g++ and Visual Studio 10 (RC freely available now)

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem with a lot of the stuff in Algorithm. It has a nasty tendency to end up being *more* code that just using an old-fashioned for loop.

I can't really justify going off and creating some special functor class (which is a moderately advanced topic in C++ that many of my maintainers won't fully understand) with a proper constructor and destructor, and perhaps some accessors, simply to avoid a one-line for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you used for_each instead of transform in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

I never use std::for_each (or very seldom).

I'd suggest using [Boost.Foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/foreach.html) and classic "for" constructions for now. And when C++0x is out, you could consider using the new "for" construct, made more readable for iterating through containers.

Comment: Can hardly wait for C++ to get a real "for" loop (rather than the glorififed while loop it has now).

Answer (score 0):

Also think of Parallelism, with a function you can define what will change and indicate if a range of elements can instead be done in Parallel rather 1 at a time from start to end.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could wait for C++0x and use `for(elem& e, container){e.something();}`
Quite the same as `BOOST_FOREACH()`, but part of the standard (in some years...).